# How to preload using where not filtering data

Tags: sql, go, filter, go-gorm

how to work with gorm with preload and filtering i have stuck for some time, maybe can help me

```
type JualmstModel struct {
    Trnjualmstoid int            `json:"jualid"`
    Trnno         string         `json:"jualno"`
    JualdtlModel  []JualdtlModel `gorm:"foreignkey:Trnjualmstoid;association_foreignkey:Trnjualmstoid"`
}

type JualdtlModel struct {
    Trnjualdtloid          int       `json:"jualdtlid"`
    Trnjualmstoid          int       `json:"jualid"`
    Item                   ItemModel `gorm:"foreignkey:itemoid;association_foreignkey:itemoid"`
    Itemoid                int       `json:"Itemoid"`
}

type ItemModel struct {
    Itemoid  string `json:"itemid"`
    Itemdesc string `json:"itemdesc"`
}
```

here is the model

```
DB.Find(b).
        Preload("JualdtlModel.Item", "itemdesc like ?", "%"+menu+"%").
        Find(b)
```

here the result

```
 "jualid": 1,
      "jualno": "INV/201902/0001",
      "JualdtlModel": [
        {
          "jualdtlid": 1,
          "jualid": 1,
          "Item": {
            "itemid": "22",
            "itemdesc": "+ KEJU"
          },
          "Itemoid": 22
        },
        {
          "jualdtlid": 2,
          "jualid": 1,
          "Item": {
            "itemid": "",
            "itemdesc": ""
          },
          "Itemoid": 87
        },
```

i want to filter the item with some menu item, but when i add filter item it not filter all of my query

here debug result

```
SELECT * FROM [trnJualMst] 

SELECT * FROM [trnJualDtl]  WHERE ([trnjualmstoid] IN (1,2,3)) 

SELECT * FROM [mstItem]  WHERE ([itemoid] IN (87,85,18,12,75,22,19,37,44,36,28,29,92,54,34)) AND (itemdesc like '%keju%')
```

What can I do so I can only load item that in filter?

Comment: Did you try taking that out of the preload clause, and instead, use joins and where functions?

Comment: can i do it with just preload only

Comment: What's the issue with the query that's being generated? Can you show the SQL that you'd like to receive?

Comment: query that i want maybe something like this.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM [trnJualMst] 
inner join trnjualdtl on [trnJualMst].trnjualmstoid = trnjualdtl.trnjualmstoid
inner join mstitem on mstitem.itemoid = trnjualdtl.itemoid
WHERE trnjualdtl.trnjualmstoid in (1,2,3) and 
([itemoid] IN (87,85,18,12,75,22,19,37,44,36,28,29,92,54,34)) AND (itemdesc like '%keju%')